# ZF2 main router in console

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

How can I use the `url()` controller helper inside the console?

I have to generate some urls using an action of the console, but if I call `$this->controller->url()->fromRoute(...);`, I can only ask for routes defined in the `console` router.

In other words, I need the ability to call all the routes of the application's main router.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, that it is a good decision, but you can change router manually:

```
// ConsoleController.php

// Change router to HTTP    
$this->getEvent()->setRouter($this->getServiceLocator()->get('HttpRouter'));

// Get any HTTP route
var_dump($this->url()->fromRoute('your_http_route'));

// Change it back, if you want
$this->getEvent()->setRouter($this->getServiceLocator()->get('Router'));
```